# Связь MS SQL с Delphi

Tags: delphi, sql-server

Каким способ (компонентом) лучше всего работать с MS SQL Server, причем чтобы без заморочек написанная программа заработала на разных компьютеров где ничего толком не стоит. Ну разве что можно еще в установщик встроить требуемые dll-ки и записать их в System32, к примеру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несомненно ADO , он же dbGo - в последних релизах. Во первых, поддерживается Microsoft - ом,полно документаций в сети,работаеть стабильно чем другие коннектора. Не требуется установить дополнительные драйвера, так как взаимодействие с сервером БД осуществляеться через самого ODBC (встроенного). Умеет делать асинхронные запросы , которые другие драйвера не поддерживаеть , пока что.

Comment: Желательно без ODBC. Потому как не у всех как оказалось установлен драйвер ODBC. Поэтому ищу другой вариант так бы я и не справшивал

Comment: ммм.понятно. тогда библиотека Зеос http://zeos.firmos.at/index.php

Comment: Zeos ? о нет, пожалуй это не вариант, пользовался я им как то крайне не понравилось мне. Есть другие варианты ?

Comment: dbExpress??

Comment: У меня кстати он почему то не подключается через него, мол просто нет соединения. Хотя может сам чего то не правильно делаю.